# Windows Notification Banner gets cut off - bug?

Tags: windows, windows-10, notification-area

Windows 10 seems to consistently display it's notifications so large that they are cut-off and impossible to read. The close button also isn't visible, let alone clickable.

This seems like a bug, but it's been the case for years without any fixes... So maybe it's just me?

I can see other examples online, but no real solutions. Example of issue:

[image: Windows 10 Notification banner cut off]

To confirm, I have very vanilla display size settings:

[image: windows display settings]

Comment: "So maybe it's just me?" - If it's been years, it's likely a device setting, provided you have been using the same device for years.  You should be able to see what the notification was for by clicking on the action center button, they notifications should still be there unless you dismissed them.  It does not appear to be any notification I recognize.

Comment: Did you switch DPI without logging out?

Comment: I've restarted the machine many many times and it's still always an issue. I do remote into the machine regularly, as well as run multiple monitors, but that has to be pretty common! I'm not the only person with the issue, eg: https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/b01lc7/notifications_cut_off/

Comment: Hence my question. Because Windows still has many bugs related to display scaling, especially concerning changing scaling levels (even when only on secondary displays).